# Elegant, Vue-only solution for getting browser width in multiple components in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm relatively new to Vue 3, working on an application in which many components need access to the value of screen width, with the necessity of updating it dynamically as the window resizes.

Is there any elegant, no-third-party-plugin solution for implementing such a variable once, and using it in multiple components, without having to add event listeners seperately inside each one of them?

I've tried to define windowWidth in `main.js` as a globalProperty, and add a window event listener:

```
import { createApp, ref } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

const app = createApp(App).use(router);

app.config.globalProperties.breakpoints = {
  sm: 768,
  md: 1024,
  lg: 1200,
};

app.config.globalProperties.winWidth = ref(window.innerWidth);

window.addEventListener(
  "resize",
  () => (app.config.globalProperties.winWidth = window.innerWidth)
);

app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

But the value does not change when I resize the window (calling `winWidth` inside a `<p>` tag in a component to test).

I would love to learn how to implement this successfully!

Comment: at first you are assigning `winWidth` with `ref`. So if when updating later (in event hadler) you should use `winWidth.value = ....`

Comment: Thank you, it works! For a small project, is it okay if the event listener is defined in the `main.js` file (it is never destroyed)?

Comment: Well it is ok even for big projects. In the end it is just one listener for the whole app.